# What is this sealed electrical component?

Tags: identification

This thing, pictured below, is part of a mower's safety electronics (the mower is a bunton model "forty eight"). All the switches to make sure you can not start the mower with the blades engaged, or in gear, and you are holding the handles run through this thing.
The only markings on it are 1200-18B and 88210 (second picture). Google has been no help with those numbers.

[image: 3/4 view of part to be identified]

[image: side view of part to be identified with markings visible]]

[image: top view of part to be identified]]

Here is a crude wiring diagram.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCUR8Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What is this, and what does it do?

Comment: probably diodes ... possibly a relay .... lawnmower make and model?

Comment: @jsotola it is a "bunton" model "forty eight" probably wont help much. you can not find manuals, or anything on it.

Comment: My guess is a HV RC snubber & relay for electric brakes to short out electric motor on stop faster or just a relay for SPDT power or brake.

Comment: is this it?  ... https://www.jackssmallengines.com/jacks-parts-lookup/manufacturer/bobcat/bunton/rotary/48-midsize/634003-14-hp-kawasaki-48-side-discharge/operator-present

Comment: really hard to say what in it, but what it does is ground the red  wire if the pre-condition is met.  red wire is probably the ground end of the starter relay or of a starter-inhibit relay.  as the circuit is powered though the red wire it's probably all solid-state, and the active component is probaly an SCR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is an "interlock module". It contains some components and an SCR. The SCR acts as a latching relay that requires no external power (other than from the low voltage side of the magneto) to maintain conduction after the engine starts.

See, for example, Patent [US4033311](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/73/e2/6f/2d061abb30059c/US4033311.pdf).

By the looks of it, the gear switches must both be closed and the handle switch maybe open for it to start. Or the handle switch may act as a kill switch so it must be closed for it to continue to run, whereas the other switches need only be closed to start it (probably more likely). In the latter case, the thyristor completes the circuit to ground from the red wire through the handle switch.

This is for the kind of engine electrical system that consists of just the magneto, no battery and therefore no starter motor, no electronic ignition and no charging circuit. Like a mechanical kill switch, it must be closed, completing the circuit- typically to ground- before the ignition spark will be generated.

Bypassing it is trivial, but not recommended, for obvious safety reasons.

Answer (score 1):

it is a `safety interlock module`

found some info here ... http://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/safety-interlock-module.4160/